# javascript window.prompt or prompt doesn't work in nativefier Electron

Tags: javascript, dom, electron, progressive-web-apps, desktop-application

i build a website to desktop app with nativefier this is the link of the example website :
https://www.javatpoint.com/oprweb/test.jsp?filename=javascript-prompt-dialog-box2

The website with the browser shows the javascript prompt box but in nativefier no
**Here is the picture in browser :**
[picture in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96Cok.png)
and **here is the picture in nativefier :**
[nativefier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qv1ZA.png)
**the alert and confirm works good only prompt/window.prompt method** ,
is there any solution with nativefier ? or prompt method alternative and thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please?

Comment: I used this tool https://github.com/nativefier/nativefier
You can test JavaScript prompt method and you will see the problem , the  prompt box don't show up